# Show and Hide note messages for a sign up page JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am pretty new to web dev and I am stuck at a point where I am trying to set up the signup page for a website. I found a pretty good [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3qyxo_UTR4) but it seems to be outdated at this point, all other functions worked fine.
The target is to show the condition notes and a hook/cross for the field that is focused. The cross should be replaced by a hook and the notes should disappear as soon as the condition is hit, so the user sees that the field is filled correctly.
The problem is that the messages, cross, and hook always stay even though the field is not in focus, the conditions fit, and the validation request turns from false to true.
I am programming with vsc with node.js and react 18.2.0.

```
> The condition <
const PWD_REGEX=/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%]).{8,24}$/;

const SignUp=() =>{

> The variables <
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [validPassword, setValidPassword]= useState(false)
const [PasswordFocus, setPasswordFocus]= useState(false)

const [matchpassword, setMatchPassword] = useState('')
const [validMatch, setValidMatch]= useState(false)
const [matchFocus, setMatchFocus]= useState(false)

> The function <
  useEffect(()=>{
    const result = PWD_REGEX.test(password)
    console.log(result)
    console.log(password)
    setValidPassword(result)
    const match = password === matchpassword
    setValidMatch(match)
  },[password, matchpassword])

> The return <
return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>            
  <label htmlFor='password'>Passwort:
       <span className={validPassword ? 'valid' : 'hide'}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck}/></span>
       <span className={validPassword || !password ? 'hide' : 'invalid'}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes}/></span>
    </label>
      <input            
          placeholder='Passwort'
          id='password'
          type='password'
          onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
          aria-invalid={validPassword ? 'false' : 'true'}
          aria-describedby='pwdnote'
          onFocus={()=> setPasswordFocus(true)}
          onBlur={()=>setPasswordFocus(false)}
      />
     <p id='pwdnote' className={PasswordFocus && !validPassword ? 'instructions' : 'offscreen'}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle}/>
          8 to 24 characters<br />
          Must contain an upper and lower case letter, a number and a special character. <br />
          Allowed special characters are:
          <span aria-label='exclamation mark'>!</span>
          <span aria-label='at symbol'>@</span>
          <span aria-label='hashtag'>#</span>
          <span aria-label='dollar sign'>$</span>
          <span aria-label='percent'>%</span>
     </p>
</form>
)
}
```

Comment: Okay, i found a solution on my own instead of the proposal in the video I have used an other method for conditional rendering:              
```{!PasswordFocus ? (<p></p>) : validPassword ? (<span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} /> </span> ) : ( <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} /> </span> )}```
Translation: If UserFocus is not true print nothing else if input of user is valid print the hook else print the X.
The same logic works for the notes:
```{!PasswordFocus ? ( <p></p> ) : validPassword  ? (<p></p> ) : (<p id="pwdnote"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />some note</p>```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the proposal in the video I have used an other method for conditional rendering:

```
{!PasswordFocus ? (<p></p>) : validPassword ? (<span><FontAwesomeIconicon={faCheck} /> </span> ) : ( <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes}/> </span> )}
```

Translation: If UserFocus is not true print nothing else if input of user is valid print the hook else print the X.
The same logic works for the notes:

```
{!PasswordFocus ? ( <p></p> ) : validPassword  ? (<p></p> ) : (<p id="pwdnote"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />some note</p>
```